# Lowercasing actions using Attribute Routing in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I am leveraging attribute routing in an MVC5 application and enjoy being able to declare conventions at the controller class level per the example below. For the actions within a controller, is there an advisable way to enforce lowercase path / url conventions? I presently override `GetAreaPrefix` in a custom `DefaultDirectRouteProvider` to enforce lowercase area prefixes but is there anything equivalent for enforcing lowercase conventions on the action's without having to place a route attribute on each one?

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
    [RouteArea("TestArea", AreaPrefix = "testarea/testpath")]
    [Route("{action=index}")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// this returns /testarea/testpath/Index (note the action is not lowercase)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this returns a properly lowercased path of /testarea/testpath/details
        /// Do we really need to put route attributes on each action? Is it possible to have a custom declaration at the class level?
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("details")]
        public ActionResult Details()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After additional research, setting the route collection LowercaseUrls property to true in `RegisterRoutes` of global.asax did the trick for me:

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
```